# Connecting Tomcat and IIS

Tags: iis, tomcat

When running on Linux I know how to connect Tomcat to Apache. But how is it done when running Windows and IIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've done this in the past using the apache mod-jk project. It is a .dll used by IIS that when configured properly, allows IIS to communicate with tomcat and serve jsps.

http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/

Comment: @Robert Munteanu: hi, I've already set up `isapi_redirect.dll`, but I'm really stuck here as I don't know how to map a Tomcat deployed application (`http://localhost:8080/my_app`) to another address which accepts requests on port 80 (e.g. `http://my_app.local`), but serves a deployed Tomcat-app. Can you help me in this: http://serverfault.com/questions/334681/iis-7-tomcat-7-how-to-reach-http-localhost8080-my-app-under-e-g-http-m ? I would be really grateful if you could suggest methods to solve the problem described there. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/iis.html) from the Tomcat how-to pages.