# IIS 7 + Tomcat 7 - how to reach http://localhost:8080/my_app under e.g. http://my_app.local

Tags: iis, iis-7, tomcat, java, iis-7.5

### In brief:

**IIS 7** + **Apache Tomcat 7** + `isapi_redirect.dll`:

I have a deployed and working Tomcat-application available under `http://localhost:8080/my_app`.
I would like to see the same content under `http://my_app.local` (and NOT the default Tomcat-site [which you can see below]).
I set up `isapi_redirect.dll`, so right now `my_app.local`'s content equals to `localhost:8080`'s, but it's not enough, I would like to map `localhost:8080/my_app` under `my_app.local`.
(I DO have `127.0.0.1  my_app.local` in hosts file, so I can already open `my_app.local`, BUT now it only shows the default Tomcat site (same as available under `http://localhost:8080`)).

Please read what I have already tried:

---

### Longer explained:

I have **IIS 7** (7.5.7600.16385) and **Apache Tomcat/7.0.22** installed.

1. I deployed an application (let's call it "`my_app`") in Tomcat,
   which now can be reached at `http://localhost:8080/my_app`, works
   fine.   I added a new web site in IIS panel with the path of the
   Tomcat deployed `my_app`, which looks like this: "`c:\Program
   Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\my_app`"
2. I binded the host name `my_app.local`.
3. After that, I configured `isapi_redirect.dll` like [this](http://mumblestiltskin.blogspot.com/2011/01/iis7-and-tomcat-basic-setup.html) (or
   [that](http://www.iisadmin.co.uk/?p=72&page=2)).
4. Now, when I open `http://my_app.local`, I can see the default Tomcat
   site (see below), which is the same as the content under `http://localhost:8080/`!! (That's the problem!!!)
5. BUT under `http://my_app.local` I would like to see the same content as
   under `http://localhost:8080/my_app`.

How can I do that? Thank you very much in advance!!

*my config files:*

- [isapi_redirect.properties](http://pastebin.com/0BYH1bie) (I made a dir junction to c:\tomcat, so this also works :) )
- [workers.properties](http://pastebin.com/EJ62iw3T)
- [uriworkermap.properties](http://pastebin.com/k5jm1xZ1)
- rewrites.properties (empty)

[image]

---

---

**UPDATE**

I found this too: http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/generic_howto/proxy.html

> Case B: You need to hide path components for all requests going to the
>   application. Here's the recipe for the case, where you want to hide
>   the first path component /myapp. More complex manipulations are left
>   as an exercise to the reader. First the solution for the case of
>   Apache httpd:
>
> 1. Use mod_rewrite to add /myapp to all requests before forwarding to the backend:
>      [...]
> 2. Use mod_headers to rewrite any HTTP redirects your application might return.
>      [...]
> 3. Use mod_headers again, to rewrite the paths contained in any cookies, your application might set.
>      [...]
>
> **If you are using Microsoft IIS** as a web server, the ISAPI plugin provides a way of doing the first step with a builtin feature. **You
>   define a mapping file** for simple prefix changes like this:
>
> ```
> # Add a context prefix to all requests ...
> /=/myapp/
> # ... or change some prefix ...
> /oldapp/=/myapp/
> ```
>
> and then put the name of the file in the `rewrite_rule_file` entry of
>   the registry or your `isapi_redirect.properties` file. In your
>   `uriworkermap.properties` file, you still need to map the URLs as they
>   are before rewriting! [...]
>   **There is no support for Steps 2 (rewriting redirect responses) or 3 (rewriting cookie paths).**

I was surprised that it writes "**There is no support for Steps 2 (rewriting redirect responses) or 3 (rewriting cookie paths).**", I don't know if it's still true, but then what? Am I stuck again?

Comment: Hi. Did you ever find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your goal (easy to remember url?), maybe it's ok to just *redirect* my_app.local -> my_app.local:8080/my_app?

This would not *hide* the target site, however.

Setup a new IIS Site at my_app.local, and let it *redirect* to your :8080/my_app app.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732930(WS.10).aspx

Comment: No, unfortunately it's not an option to simply REDIRECT the address, I should serve the content of the site via the 80 port. For example, via IIS, I can serve ASP.NET or PHP pages too, through the 80th port, after installing the FastCGI PHP extension.

Comment: Effectively, what you want is a reverse proxy from iis to tomcat, right? See my other answer then.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:
http://blogs.iis.net/carlosag/archive/2010/04/01/setting-up-a-reverse-proxy-using-iis-url-rewrite-and-arr.aspx

This seems to be what you need, URL Rewriting & Application Routing.